# New to Photoshop need help saving PSD file as TIFF file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, tiff

I've just created my first photoshop image however as I was saving it, photoshop said that layers will make the file size bigger. I don't want this to happen so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. This is a very basic Photoshop operation, and you can certainly get the answer in the Adobe website or Photoshop documentation / forums. If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have you thought to flatten the layers before saving the file as a TIFF?
   OR
2. While saving you may check off the option "Layers" so it would save it as flatten image.
   OR
3. After clicking save you might check the radio button option "skip/omit the layers and save as a copy". I dunno how it's written in english, I have Photoshop version in my language :( , but that's the meaning of this option.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not show any effort / research.

The above answer is correct, if transparency is not important to you.  Once the image is flattened, it will have a solid (white by default) background colour.  As you did not state why you chose the TIFF format, one can only guess what answer would best serve you.

If another format is okay, and you want to maintain transparency, you can go to `File » Save As` and choose PNG.  Or `File » Save For Web` and select PNG which will give you more control over the colour palette and file-size.  The large size of TIFFs make them well-suited for high-resolution print graphics and photography, but not most beginner tasks.

Whichever option you choose, it is important to `Save As a Copy` if you are going to flatten the image, so that you preserve the layers and keep them editable.